# Microprofile java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream incompatible

Tags: microprofile

I'm using microprofile 3.2 to call out to a rest webservice that returns a java bean in a Response entity. When I try to extract the bean from the response though I get a

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream incompatible with <class>
```

error.

E.g.

My bean:

```
public class MyBean {
    private int id;
    public int getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(final int id) { this.id = id; }
}
```

REST WS api interface:

```
@GET
@Path("/{id}")
Response getBean(@PathParam("id") Integer id);
```

REST implementation class:

```
public Response getBean(final Integer id) {
    MyBean myBean = new Service().getBean(id);
    return Response.ok(myBean).build();
}
```

RestClient:

```
IBeanResource beanResource = 
RestClientBuilder.newBuilder().baseUri(apiURI).build(IBeanResource.class);
Response beanResponse = beanResource.getBean(100);
if (beanResponse.getStatus() == Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode()) {
    MyBean bean = (MyBean) beanResponse.getEntity();
}
```

Error fires on line

```
MyBean bean = (MyBean) beanResponse.getEntity();
```

Has anyone seen this before? The documentation isn't great.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that would be the expected behavior. If you inspect the value of `beanResponse` in debug you will see the Response is of type `InboundJaxrsResonse` and entity is nothing but of type `HttpUrlConnector`. Which is why when you try to cast it to your custom bean class it throws `ClassCastException`. You can try any of the following approach:

1. you could instead do as below

   `String jsonString = beanResponse.readEntity(String.class);`

The above will give you the JSON response as String and then you may convert it to your respective class using libraries such as gson or jackson of your choice.

2. In your REST WS api interface instead of returning `Response` return your model `MyBean`. As per the Microprofile rest Client spec it states the implementation of Microprofile Rest client must provide a built-in JSON-P entity provider and if it supports JSON-B then it must provide JSON-B entity provider.

[microprofile-rest-client-spec-2.0](https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-rest-client-2.0/microprofile-rest-client-spec-2.0.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. I'll take a look at the spec again for returning models. I like the idea of capturing the response rather than the model so I have any header or status information too e.g. how would a 404 be handed if the resource could not be found?

I was able to get around this by reading the InputStream and using jsonb to bind to the bean

```
InputStream is = (InputStream) beanResponse.getEntity();
return jsonb.fromJson(is, MyBean.class);
```